# Is there a way to peek logged message in the C# code in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I need to find a way to configure log4net in the code (c#) on global application level so that every time a particular string appears in the logged message (all levels or one selected level) an action delegate is invoked. 
That seems to be quite basic feature but I couldn't find any resouces on that so far.

Thanks, Radek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to "peek". Use additional appender - [MemoryAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_MemoryAppender.htm).
And use its GetEvents method to periodically check all logged messages and if you find the relevant message, publish some event etc.

Comment: I created a custom appender derived from AppenderSkeleton. I was able to get to the messages at the time it was logged. I guess MemoryAppender will work too. Thanks.